# property of a subgroup generated by two subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Let $A, B, C$ be subgroups of a finite group $G$. Is it true that the following holds:

$$\langle A,B\rangle\cap C=\langle A\cap C, B\cap C\rangle$$

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $A=\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z \oplus 0, B = 0 \oplus \Bbb Z/n \Bbb Z$ and $C = \langle (1,1) \rangle$ as subgroups of $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^2$. We have
$$C = (\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^2 \cap C = \langle A, B\rangle \cap C$$
but
$$ 0 = \langle 0,0\rangle = \langle A \cap C, B\cap C\rangle.$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. We can take, for example, $G=S_5$, $A=A_5$, $B=\langle(12)\rangle$ and $C=\langle (13)\rangle$. Then $\langle A,B\rangle=S_5$ and $\langle A,B\rangle\cap C=C$. On the other hand, $A\cap C=B\cap C=1$ and so $\langle A\cap C, B\cap C\rangle=1\neq C=\langle A,B\rangle\cap C$.